# How to detect collision between two QGraphicsPixmapItems if the pixmaps' edges are transparent?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, collision, qpixmap

I have two `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s, the edges of both are transparent and they aren't rectangle shaped. When I try to use `QGraphicsItem::collidingItems()`, it only checks if their bounding rects are colliding. Is there a way to detect the collision only of the non-transparent parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the shape mode to [`QGraphicsPixmapItem::HeuristicMaskShape`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspixmapitem.html#ShapeMode-enum):

> **QGraphicsPixmapItem::HeuristicMaskShape**
>
> The shape is determine by calling QPixmap::createHeuristicMask(). The
>   performance and memory consumption is similar to MaskShape

---

```
your_item->setShapeMode(QGraphicsPixmapItem::HeuristicMaskShape);
```

Example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>

#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsView w;
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    w.setScene(scene);

    QList<QGraphicsPixmapItem *> items;

    for(const QString & filename: {":/character.png", ":/owl.png"}){
        QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = scene->addPixmap(QPixmap(filename));
        item->setShapeMode(QGraphicsPixmapItem::HeuristicMaskShape);
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
        item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
        items<<item;
    }

    items[1]->setPos(50, 22);
    if(items[0]->collidingItems().isEmpty())
        qDebug()<<"there is no intersection";
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

output:

```
there is no intersection
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49803820)

Comment: I've already tried this, but it didn't work.
`model->setShapeMode(QGraphicsPixmapItem::HeuristicMaskShape);`
I set both to Heuristic map.

Comment: @SkipperHUN 
I have tried it and it works correctly, maybe your image does not have transparencies, you could share the image in a zip.

Comment: [Here is the picture, it's not the final image obviously, but it should still work.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RBkAHfXIGZWAv08LpGAfAA_EdMu0ZycE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @SkipperHUN 
I have added an example, download it and execute it, it works correctly for me.

Comment: Your code works for me too, but somehow it doesn't work in my project. I decided to use another solution, which might even work better than how this would have worked. Thank you for your help though.